# How can I not trigger jobs when new branch is created?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I noticed that when I create a new branch, Gitlab-CI is triggered to run the job. How do I disable this in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: there may be some way to do that using [rules](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/yaml/README.md#rules), but you'll probably have to figure out a way to obtain the info that your commit just duplicated a branch and check against that in an `if` condition

Comment: hmm ok, I'm just a week into GitLab CI, still learning~ I will pursue into the direction u suggested and see if I can find a solution to it~ will post here if I do~ thanks :)

Comment: you'll likely run into the problem that it's very difficult to distinguish between a "create new branch" action in Gitlab - which adds no changes to its original branch - and a push to a new branch from a local repository (which may very well have significant commit changes). I guess checking that by Gitlab-CI's means would require you to do some scripting outside Gitlab-CI in order to evaluate significance of changes, and then setting some CI variable that you'd then have to check for in order to determine whether to run CI or not. More work than it's worth, imho.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found for a GitLab CI pipeline to discern whether the triggering event was the creation of a new branch is to check `CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA`, which [the docs state](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html):

> Is always 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 in merge request pipelines and for the first commit in pipelines for branches or tags.

Below I'm using it to run a special stage that runs only when a new branch, matching a predefined regex, is created:

```
  variables:
    BRANCH_REGEX: "/${DEPLOY_ENVIRONMENT}.+/"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" && '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ $BRANCH_REGEX'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"
    when: never
```

or use the outlined `if:` condition in any number of jobs you do not want to have started on branch creation. Note, however, that this condition also (to my understanding) suppresses pipelines if you make any commits via WebIDE. If you insist on having those, you'll probably have to check for `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != "webide"` (but I have not tested if that works).

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure your pipeline do not run on branches

```
except:
  - branches
```

put this in each step of your pipeline

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

Comment: this implies the pipeline will never be triggered by any commit on a branch, which I'm not sure is what OP is actually looking for. At least as far as I understood, they only want to drop CI for the commit resulting from forking a branch in gitlab

Comment: hmm, that wouldn't work, cos I still want the branches to execute jobs when someone push changes to branches. I just want to restrict jobs from triggering on new branch creations.